# What is the shortest term to refer to people whose mother tongue is English?

Tags: vocabulary, single-word-requests, technical

What is the shortest term to refer to representatives of peoples and cultures whose mother tongue is English?

[Mothertonguers?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/meaning-of-the-phrase-in-the-wash)

Update:
Can't I [call them joe](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11538/origin-of-the-meaning-of-joe/12442#12442)?

Comment: I can't help but think of `mothertonguers` as ... something else.

Comment: If you are speaking to a person who is a native speaker of English, you can use _you_.

Comment: And how would I know that a person with whom I am speaking is a native English speaker??? No, this is question how [to refer to strangers in Tweets](http://twitter.com/#!/vgv8/status/36284025022849024). Besides, if I correctly remember, ["4 years ago I happily dumped all my micros"](http://twitter.com/#!/vgv8) and became [write-only](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12182/is-im-write-only-comprehensible)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

*Native [anglophone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglophone)* is, I believe, an even shorter term.

> **anglophone** *(noun)*
>   an English-speaking person
>
> ---
>
> <sup>[Oxford Dictionaries](http://oxforddictionaries.com/view/entry/m_en_us1221862#m_en_us1221862)</sup>

Comment: And we are anglofiles, right?

Comment: @mplungian: If you mean you like English people, you are an Anglophile.

Comment: @Robusto: I like people who speak English. Does that make me an Anglophonophile? ;)

Comment: Anglophone only means speaks English. The question was a term for someone who was a native English speaker

Comment: @Martin: That's why my answer was "native anglophone".

Answer (score 20):

Native English speakers.

I do not believe that the term "mothertonguers" would be generally well received.

Comment: ...or understood properly.

Comment: exactly, was confused when I first saw it in http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/6361/meaning-of-the-phrase-in-the-wash

Comment: "I do not believe that the term 'mothertonguers' would be generally well received": A masterpiece of understatement.

Comment: Besides, **everyone** has a monthertongue... and it isn't English for most of them.

Answer (score 1):

In England, we tend to use a phrase (term?) popularised by Winston Churchill in a book he wrote in the early 20th Century. The phrase is "*the English speaking peoples*".

Not as humorous (nor as open to misinterpretation) as mothertonguers. :-)

You won't find too many people on the streets of London who would understand what you were talking about if you asked them, 'Are you an Anglophone?' Don't think you'd offend anyone, but don't believe they'd have a clue what you were asking them either. More than likely, they'd think you wanted to borrow (or steal!) their mobile phone (translation: *cellphone*).

If you were asking what is the correct *racial* name for someone (in the UK) who is English by descent, a pretty common term is *Anglo-Saxon*. But even most (British) people of Celtic origin (i.e. Scottish, Welsh, Irish, Cornish) nowadays only speak English.

Nearly all former British colonies, including (but not limited to) the present-day Commonwealth, are inhabited mainly by people whose "mother tongue" is English. So you're really asking for a term that describes or includes dozens of countries. But **English-speaking** (native English-speaking?) is the best description we've ever been able to come up with.

Really, there is no term (today) for people who speak English. There used to be! Once-upon-a-time they were called **Englishmen**.  :-)

Answer (score -3):

"Anglos" would also be an appropriate term according to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anglo).

Comment: -1: "Anglo", at least in the US, is understood as referring to a person whose ethnic and cultural background can be traced to England.  If you referred to a native English speaker of African or Latino descent as an "Anglo", you would certainly cause confusion and very likely offense.

Answer (score -8):

[English is no one's (person or country) native language](http://www.mothertongue.com/wordpress/?p=488). And hence, there is no term that has ever been coined to refer people whose mother tongue is English. Hence, it will be like talking something south of the south pole.

Comment: Native language refers to the language you have learned while growing up (native = from birth). Plenty of people have learned English in their formative years and they are called anglophones, as pointed out by Jimi.

Comment: English is the native language of England.